# Incorrect Format Validation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, format

How can I show a modal popup on my save button that tells the format of the inputted data is incorrect?

This is my code for my input field:

```
  <input class="inputs len_md" name="number" ng-model="myModel.text"  required  ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" / >
```

My button is as follow:

```
 <button type="submit" class="button" Save</button><br><br><br>
```

My Modal popup is

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content" ng-hide="incorrect_format" id="incorrect_format">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
    <h6 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Error</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" >
    <p><center>The format is incorrect.</center> </p>


  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I display the popup on button click that checks the correct format validation? Im using angularjs btw. Thanks for any help

Comment: which ui framework you are use?

Comment: not mvc i mean bootstrap for modal or other design framework

Comment: haha :D I'm sorry. Bootstrap @PareshGami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check validation from controller and show modal if it is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input class="inputs len_md" name="number" ng-model="myModel.text"  required  ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" / >

<button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="upd_check()">Save</button><br><br><br>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
                <h6 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Error</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
                <p><center>The format of Max UDP Connection is incorrect.</center> </p>
                <p><center>Please enter a number from 0~65535.</center> </p>
                <p><center>(0 means no limit)</center> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.upd_check = function(value)
    {
        var patt = new RegExp("/^(\d)+$/");
        var res = patt.test(value);

        if(!res)
        {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
    }

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where will I put this @PareshGami?

Comment: when you click button at that time any function should call in controller at that time you need to show modal using above code if format is wrong

Comment: If its not too much of your time, can you give me a sample demo? @PareshGami I'm new in angularjs and still exploring things up Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for this @PareshGami but even if I entered a correct format it still displays the modal for incorrect format

Comment: how about if the entered input is in correct format? The code still displays the modal but it shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to show this pop-up only when the user enters information that is not a number between 0 - 65535.

For this, you first need to add an ng-click event to the button which runs a function with the mymodel.text variable as a parameter.  The function will determine whether or not the user entered a number (most basic validator).  This could look like:

```
var validator = function(mymodel.text){
     if (mymodel.text === NaN){
     incorrect_format = false;
     }
}
```

And would be called by the button like:

```
<button ng-click = "validator()" type="submit" class="button" Save</button><br><br><br>
```

This would then change the condition of the variable to false and would result in the ng-hide function ceasing to execute and showing the modal pop-up.

Comment: @ bleykFaust mm long shot here, but I noticed your button is missing a closing tag in the example

Comment: Yah Thanks for that @maxwell but It's still not working :3